# Весь урон повышается на 2

Tags: семантика

Есть игра, где существа вызываются с помощью карт. Эти существа умеют атаковать противника по определенным правилам. У этих существ есть базовая атака и модификаторы.

Вопрос такой.
Какой урон будет нанесен противнику пятью существами с атакой 3, если модификатор звучит следующим образом:
**"...весь урон нанесенный противнику повышается на 2"**?

У моих друзей получилось 2 варианта ответа с разными цифрами из-за разногласий в интерпретации выделенного условия. 
Можно ли на обозначенный вопрос дать однозначный ответ?

Для примера, как игроки понимают выделенную выше фразу:

а) (3+2)+(3+2)+(3+2)+(3+2)+(3+2) = (3+2)*5 = 25

б) (3+3+3+3+3)+2 = 17

Comment: А нет ли в этом выражении чудес любительского перевода? Про-русски эти 2 (балла?) должны прибавляться к урону. А что, если в оригинале имелось в виду умножение на два (удвоение ущерба)?

Comment: Это перевод. В оригинале фраза звучит так: While Justicar is unblocked all damage done to the opponent is increased by 2. Но проблема в ожидаемой итоговой цифре урона, после прочтения русского перевода.

Comment: Хотелось бы подтверждения любого из предложенных выше вариантов, как единственно верного (а или б) и обоснования, почему второй вариант неверен.

Comment: Не получите вы подтверждения. Надо смотреть английский контекст. Или ставить эксперимент. Потому, что термин "весь урон" (all damage) совершенно не самоочевиден в свете ваших сомнений. Даже если мы придем к какому-то решению, где гарантия, что автор текста рассуждал также, когда это все писал?

Answer (score 1):

Приведенная Вами формулировка не дает возможности однозначно понять авторскую мысль. Её надо править. Это все, что имеет отношение к русскому языку. Гадать на кофейной гуще не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Весь (по Ожегову) — полный, целиком, всё, что в наличии. Поэтому, думаю, сначала всё суммируете, потом прибавляете. В Вашем примере б, 17. Первый пример был бы со словом "каждый".

Comment: Вот другие варианты ответов: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1872265-ves-uron-pri-atake-dvuh-suschestv-na-3-uvelichen-na-2-itogovyj-uron.html#answer5539107